# aurelia bundle - serve from a single directory

Tags: aurelia

Trying to use the [aurelia cli](https://github.com/aurelia/cli) bundling facility.

Is it possible to serve all app files (i.e. index.html, app-bundle.html, app-bundle.js, etc) from a single directory or index.html must be at the top (./) directory and the other files in a child (./dist) directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the covers the cli is using JSPM / System.js's bundling functionality.  This works by looking at your config.js paths on where to find the files both for the bundle and when serving.  If your paths are set up to serve from the root directory this should work as expected.  The problem will be that if you are trying to bundle root it will try to grab all .js files in there which could be bad if you don't exclude them.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. [This solution](http://patrickwalters.net/my-best-practices-for-aurelia-bundling-and-minification/) to the problem of bundling has been available since April. Is 'aurelia cli' essentially doing the same thing? If so, it's ok, but I'm sure that everybody would look forward to some more high level functionality, for example not having to exclude files in the root path to make bundling work.

Comment: Yes that is correct, the CLI bundling wasn't really available until recently.  If you find that the CLI isn't fitting your needs you can use that blog post to come up with your own strategy thats a bit more in depth.